# Repainting JFrame with a different image? Allowing user to select theme

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Im building a tetris game, and I thought I'd add a couple different features to it for fun. I want to build different "themes" or "game modes", that will change the tetris layout color etc. Right now my tetris game, is modeled after the classic arcade style game, and I want the user to be able to select a theme so everything will go black, even the pieces, it's called dark mode. They should only be able to see the next piece coming. So I want to be able to repaint my background just, Color.BLACK, but since the default mode is arcade mode, arcade mode has an image being painted in the background, so Color.BLACK just gets painted under it. How do I remove that image? Also, if any of you have any crazy ideas for the game let me know!

here is my "arcade mode" (still working on design):

[image]

Comment: What do you currently have for code in your paint() method in your JComponent?

Comment: @DavidKoelle  I was using paint before, it painted the image, but I instead started using this instead this.setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File(BACKGROUND))))); and it works just as well, should I go back to using the paint method?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue! Instead of changing from an image to a color, i just instead painted my JFrame with a black image. I then had made the mistake of calling repaint, which is what would screw up my GUI. After painting the background, all of my panels would disappear, so I had to re-add those panels when selecting dark mode. Im sure there is a better way of doing that, but this works also.